# When having multiple firing rules in Tag Manager - "and" or "or"?

Tags: google-tag-manager, tag-manager

Let us say I have some tag in Tag Manager.

This event has two firing rules:

1. "All pages"
2. "Domain equals domain.com"

Is this seen as an:

(1) AND (2)

or:

(1) OR (2)

This is quite important for how to add the rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is answered in Googles own documentation:

> A tag will fire whenever any one of its firing rules is met. For
>   example, if a tag has two firing rules, one for "all pages" and
>   another for "only page ABC", the tag will fire on all pages.

So... It is "OR".